# Database on the webserver shows greek character as symbols while on xampp everything is working

Tags: php, mysql, character

I have a local database on xampp and works fine. I uploaded the database on the web server and the greek characters are showing as symbols. No matter if a create the database or uploaded on the server the problem is still there.
Below i have screen shots of the database connection,the database structure , the php and the javascript. There is also the result at the table of the database. The three first lines is with greek characters added with the xampp and then i uploaded and then it started to show greek as symbols.

This is for database connection

```
<?php

// For add - update and delete
$hostname = "localhost";
$user = "*****";
$password = "*********";  
$database = "app_foros";

$connect= new mysqli ($hostname, $user, $password, $database);//_connect

mysqli_query($connect,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

?>
```

This is for adding data

```
<?php
include('db.php');

$expences=$_POST["expences"];
$expences6 = $_POST["expences6"];
$expences13 = $_POST["expences13"];
$expences24 = $_POST["expences24"];

$expenceDif = $_POST["expenceDif"];
$datepicker = $_POST["datepicker"];
$greek = $_POST["greek"];


$connect=mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $password, $database);

$input=mysqli_query($connect,"insert into exoda
(expences,expences6,expences13,expences24,
expenceDif,datepicker,greek) 
    values  ('$expences','$expences6','$expences13','$expences24',
'$expenceDif','$datepicker','$greek')");
if($input==true){
    echo"Καταχώρηση πώλησης!";
    }else{
        echo "ΔΕΝ ΚΑΤΑΧΩΡΗΘΗΚΕ!";
    }
    
?>
```

This is Javascript

```
$("#save").click(function(){


var date = document.getElementById("getDate");


let getDate = date.value; //document.getElementById("getDate");
let expences6 = document.getElementById("expence").value;
let expence13 = document.getElementById("expence13").value;
let expence24 = document.getElementById("expence24").value;
let addValue = document.getElementById("addValue").value;

let greek = "Δοκιμές ξανα και ";
let expenceDif = newFpa24.value;
    //alert(addValue)

 alert(greek);  
     $.post('data/salesadd.php', {expences:addValue,   expences6:expences6, expences13:expence13, 
        expences24:expence24,expenceDif:expenceDif, 
datepicker:getDate, greek:greek}, function(data){
    alert(data);

    expence.value="";
    expence13.value="";
    expence24.value="";
    expence24.value="";
    addValue.value="";

    expence0.focus();

 });

});
```

This HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="el">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Ισοζύγιο τρεχουσών συναλλαγών</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap522/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0 /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/
bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

On below i have screenshots of the database structure and showing the problem

[Database connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcAqw.png)
[Adding data php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veKRk.png)
[Javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjImy.png)
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HO9u.png)
[Table data result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSHAq.png)
[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sphll.png)
[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uPae.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Please provide `SELECT HEX(col), col ...` to show what is actually stored.

Comment: Thank you for your help @RickJames  , This is what i get from the column greek:  Î”Î¿ÎºÎ¹Î¼Î­Ï‚ Î¾Î±Î½Î± ÎºÎ±Î¹  C38EE2809DC38EC2BFC38EC2BAC38EC2B9C38EC2BCC38EC2AD...

Comment: @RickJames i read your documents but it also was hard to find the solution. I would appreciate if you could help me as i dont have your experience. Thank you in advance

Comment: That's **Double encoding**.  I added an Answer to crudely address your specific situation.

Comment: Thank you again @Rick James. I know that the problem is when sending the data because if i save something or update the data in the servers database manually it stores the data in greek characters with no problem and when i am calling the data from the database it appears ok. But i dont know how to fix the problem. I believe that the problem occured from the php code when it sends the data to stored. I have no problem to give you access in order to check it.

Comment: @Anny -- Caution:  Your browser may "fix" certain errors for you.  That is why I asked to get `HEX()`.  That is, it may "appear OK", but not "be OK".

Comment: Likely causes involve configuration errors in LOAD DATA, establishing the connection, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like "double encoding"; see my [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for further discussion of that.

Since it is "Mojibake" performed twice, it is hard to figure out.  I recommend studying what I say about that and see if that happened twice -- perhaps when copying the data twice.

While it is possible to "fix" the data, you will really need to fix the cause. The data was mangled twice (or thrice?) by treating UTF-8 as latin1.

- The bytes to be stored need to be UTF-8-encoded.  What is the application's language?  PHP literals?  Some datafile?  Java?  etc.
- The connection when INSERTing and SELECTing text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4.  This, too, is application-specific.
- The column needs to be declared (or defaulted) `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`). Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see the setting.

Simple Mojibake:

```
CONVERT(CONVERT(BINARY('Δοκιμ') USING latin1) USING utf8mb4) --> 
        Î”Î¿ÎºÎ¹Î¼
```

Double encoding:

```
HEX(CONVERT(CONVERT(BINARY('Δοκιμ') USING latin1) USING utf8mb4)) -->
        C38EE2809DC38EC2BFC38EC2BAC38EC2B9C38EC2BC
```

Back the other way (shown as 2 steps):

```
CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('C38EE2809DC38EC2BFC38EC2BAC38EC2B9C38EC2BC')
          USING %s) USING utf8mb4) -->
       Î”Î¿ÎºÎ¹Î¼

CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT('Î”Î¿ÎºÎ¹Î¼' USING latin1)) USING utf8) -->
       Δοκιμ
```

If possible, fix the code, drop the table, and rebuild the table.

Comment: Thank you again @Rick James. I know that the problem is when sending the data because if i save something or update the data in the servers database manually it stores the data in greek characters with no problem and when i am calling the data from the database it appears ok.  But i dont know how to fix the problem. I believe that the problem occured from the php code when it sends the data to stored. I have no problem to give you access in order to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the error.
The problem occured because the php file with the connection to the database set the character to UTF-8 as you can see above but by a mistake i had another connection ($connect) to the php file who added the data to the database and that created a new possible connection with new set character (i dont know what) and made the double or triple encoding.
I remove it and everything is working fine.
Thank you all for reply to my problem.